# Sum with two column is SQL Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two columns in a SQL table and I need a third column with the sum of the other two.

It's possible to add a calculated column?

```sql
SELECT  WRAP_DURATION, IS_SERV_TYP_FLAG, 
FROM RVM_DM.FACT_INTERACTION_SEGMENT
```

Comment: `SELECT  WRAP_DURATION, IS_SERV_TYP_FLAG, WRAP_DURATION + IS_SERV_TYP_FLAG...`

Comment: I think SQL cannot hurt if you try to write some intuitive expressions for testing purposes. You can also check [SQL tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql/info) to find useful links to tutorials and common questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible. I did this in the following query, of course, if the columns are numeric

```
SELECT Col1,Col2,SUM(Col1 + Col2) AS Column3
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY Col1,Col2
```

If you want to combine two columns, use the following query

```
SELECT Col1,Col2,CONCAT(Col1,' ', Col2) AS Column3,
FROM yourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Example

```
SELECT Col1,Col2,nvl(Col1,0) + nvl(Col2,0) AS Column3
FROM yourTable
```

Try this

```
SELECT  WRAP_DURATION, IS_SERV_TYP_FLAG, NVL(WRAP_DURATION,0) +  NVL(IS_SERV_TYP_FLAG,0) SUM_OF_TWO_COL
FROM RVM_DM.FACT_INTERACTION_SEGMENT
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle supports generated columns, so you can just add this to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE RVM_DM.FACT_INTERACTION_SEGMENT ADD calculated INT
    GENERATED ALWAYS AS (WRAP_DURATION + IS_SERV_TYP_FLAG);
```

This becomes part of the table definition -- and the value is always correct because it is calculated when it is queried.

I will say that it seems odd to add a flag to a duration, but this works for most expressions that use only columns in one row (or constants).

Answer (score 0):

**Oracle offered a virtual column you do with this.**

syntax of a virtual column:

column_name [data_type] [GENERATED ALWAYS] AS (expression) [VIRTUAL]

In this syntax:

First, specify the name ( column_name) of the virtual column.
Second, specify the virtual column’s data type. If you omit the data type, the virtual column will take the data type of the result of the expression.
Third, specify an expression in parentheses after the AS keyword. The values of the virtual column will derive from the expression.

**1) Creating a table with a virtual column example**

create table RVM_DM.FACT_INTERACTION_SEGMENT (
WRAP_DURATION     number,
IS_SERV_TYP_FLAG  number,
CALC_SUM          number generated always as (NVL(WRAP_DURATION,0) +  NVL(IS_SERV_TYP_FLAG,0)) virtual
);

**2) Adding a virtual column to an existing table example**

ALTER TABLE RVM_DM.FACT_INTERACTION_SEGMENT
ADD (
CALC_SUM AS (NVL(WRAP_DURATION,0) +  NVL(IS_SERV_TYP_FLAG,0))
);